# AirPlay Quality Issues from iPad

Tags: ipad, appletv, airplay

I have a 1st gen iPad 32GB + WiFi and AppleTV 2nd gen.

I'm having issues playing back streaming content from my iPad to my AppleTV over AirPlay.  An example of this is audio from Pandora (Internet), and another is playing back films from Movies (local). When streamed to my iPad and then to AppleTV via AirPlay, it is "choppy" by the time it gets to the AppleTV.

When attempting the same thing from my iPhone 4S, I have no issues.

What gives?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting both iPad and AppleTV ?

Comment: Simultaneously?

Comment: No, that would not make any difference - I just meant: restart both devices (sequentially or parallel) and try if AirPlay streaming is fluid again. Btw. was it ever fluid from the iPad or always choppy ?

Comment: @iolsmit - post your comment as an answer please.  rebooting both devices fixed the issue.  never would have thought about that course of action with non-Windows devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Restart both devices and try if AirPlay streaming is fluid again.

If that should not work you can try restoring one or both devices as described in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/38744/14994) by [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike)

Answer (score 1):

Since the iPhone 4S reportedly works, I excluded network bandwith as a posible bottleneck.

iPhone 4S has much more processing power than the 1st gen iPad. If this is not something that used to work and broke, I suspect the iPad is not fit for the task. If it used to work, it could be a software/iOS update that caused it to stop working.

If I understood correctly you are streaming twice: from Internet (Padora) or network computer (Movies) to iPad and then from iPad to AppleTV. You could try to stream directly to AppleTV.

Comment: It never did work with the iPad, though I guess I can't understand why it wouldn't if they make it available as a service.  If the device isn't up to the task, why expose the feature?

Comment: @AJ. - It probably works ok with low(er) bitrate streams.

Comment: I'm going to try streaming music that is already downloaded to the iPad via AirPlay tonight.  If the content is local, it should be improved quality according to your theory.

Comment: I have the original iPad (16Gb wi-fi only) and use it to stream internet (HD video and audio) content to my apple TV all the time.  Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

If your iPad has 3G, place it in Airplane mode, then connect to the same Wi-Fi network as the Apple TV.

Comment: Clarified versions in my question...

Comment: You can't even airplay to the device if you're not on the same wi-fi network

Answer (score 0):

Something that *could* explain things:

The iPad supports 5Ghz wifi networks which normally won't be susceptible to as much interference but have less range (and depending on what other devices you or your neighbors have COULD suffer more interference).

The iPhone only supports 2.4Ghz wifi networks.

If your router supports both make sure your iPad is using the 2.4Ghz network.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting full bars on the iPad?   My router is in the basement and has some interference coming up stairs.

I had some lag to my Apple TV so I picked up an Airport Express and extended/boosted the network upstairs.

Huge improvement.